# Getting data to a fragment from the parent class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have my settings.java and my fragment.java.

In the fragment (that exists in my settings.java) I have a randomized number to set a view. Which works perfectly. I'm trying to change it from a random int to something pulled out of shared prefs. In my settings.java I have a method:

```
public int getHour() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        int timeout = settings.getInt("timeout_hour", 8);
        return timeout;
    }
```

and I call this in my fragment.java by saying
`...settings.getHour();`
But this causes it to crash. If I simply replace it with a random int (any int) `...8` the program runs perfectly. Why does my app run when I just have the number 8, but when `getHour()` returns a number (8 in this case) it fails. Is this some kind of limitation with fragments?

Comment: Please provide a crash log. And more code needed to understand what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Because settings is a local variable to getHour() function. If you want to access it inside your fragment make it a field and provide a public getter function getSettings(). Then get activity instance in fragment by

```
activity = (Settings) getActivity();
```

Now access settings by

```
activity.getHour()
```

inside fragment.

Comment: Hmm... I feel like your code is on the right track, but I feel like you should read my questions again. I don't have anything called getSettings(). What do you mean by that?

Comment: See edited post. You want to access getHour() inside your fragment, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do, I will try it later when I'm home. Thank you